# I want to make react checkbox mandatory

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to make it necessary to mark the React js checkbox component. I want to show warning icon when Checkbox is not selected. How can I do that? I shared the component I wrote below.

**React checkbox component**

```js
const CheckBox = ({
  question,
  formKey,
  valid = true,
  validationError = 'Field is required',
}) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const reduxValue = useSelector(state => state.app.forms.f3[formKey].value)
  const isSaved = useSelector(state => state.app.forms.f3[formKey].saved)

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    value: reduxValue,
    valid: true,
  })

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col className="col-1">
          <label className="orange-checkbox-container">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={formKey}
              onChange={(e) => changeSelected(e)}
              checked={input.value}
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </Col>
        <Col className="col-11">
          <p>{question}</p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <div
        className="invalid-feedback"
        style={{
          width: '8rem',
        }}
      >
        {validationError}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will improve on Han's answer. You should hide the whole `div` if there the checkbox was selected. I improved how the onChange works and separated states. Using hooks [you can separate your state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) values rather than the approach used in classes where you have 1 object `this.state = {}` to manage the whole state of that component.

```js
const CheckBox = ({
  question,
  formKey,
  // valid = true,
  validationError = 'Field is required',
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const reduxValue = useSelector(state => state.app.forms.f3[formKey].value);
  const isSaved = useSelector(state => state.app.forms.f3[formKey].saved);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(reduxValue);
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(true);

  const handleCheckedChange = event => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col className="col-1">
          <label className="orange-checkbox-container">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={formKey}
              onChange={handleCheckedChange}
              checked={checked}
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </Col>
        <Col className="col-11">
          <p>{question}</p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      {!checked &&
        <div
          className="invalid-feedback"
          style={{
            width: '8rem',
          }}
        >
          {validationError}
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should declare the initial state of valid to false and display validationError if `input.value` is `false`  I assume your onChange is changing the input.value.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({
        value: reduxValue,
        valid: false,
    })


    <div
        className='invalid-feedback'
        style={{
            width: '8rem',
        }}
    >
        {!input.value && validationError}
    </div>
```